# How to test two databases to find out missing records?

Tags: mysql, testing

I have two MySQL databases DB1 and DB2. DB1 has only 1 table with huge no of columns. All this data is being transferred and is split and stored in several tables (say 2) in DB2.

```
For example, DB1 has a table1 which looks like

        Student_Name   Id   Address   Attendance   Marks
        ------------   --   -------   ----------   -----
        John            1   90th st       70         90

The records that are transferred from DB1.table1 are stored in DB2.table and DB2.table2 in the following manner

DB2.table 1: Id   Student_Name   Address   
             --   ------------   -------
             1     John          90th st


DB2.table 2: Id   Attendance   Marks
             --   ----------   -----
             1     70            90
```

DB2 is daily updated with the new records from DB1. Now i want to come up with some test cases to find out if any records aren't being copied from DB1 to DB2 due to some reasons (ex : if Id is missing the the record is not copied).

I've never written any test cases of this kind. I need some help or can anyone suggest any plans like how can i kick start the tests. Are there any tools using which i can use to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This will eat resources, but:

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM DB2.table1 UNION SELECT id FROM DB2.table2);
```

Comment: Is this the only way to test? Because i've already tried this. I wanna find more better ways to do this.

Comment: Probably not, but it's the simplest and answers your question--it will tell you if there are any missing records.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for QA as part of the conversion process, export DB1 in its current format, then export DB2 in the same format as DB1.  Use `diff`.

If you'd like to do it online, put a 'conversion_date' column in DB2 to limit the number of records that you need to examine in the query that @zebediah49 gave you.

Or how about a trigger in DB2 that updates DB1 to mark the record as "received"?

The world is your oyster.

Comment: DB2 that updates DB1 to mark the record as "received"? how is this possible?

Comment: On DB2, you can `CREATE TRIGGER foo AFTER INSERT` that can run an `UPDATE` on DB1.  [The doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) should help.